# Skateboard ramp in Gazebo editor

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone,
I'm trying to get a skateboard ramp in the Gazebo editor, something similar to this: https://ultimatesportsonline.com/product/oc-ramps-16-half-pipe-skateboard-ramp-kit/. Any suggestion?

I've seen a similar question asked here: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5737/how-to-create-a-sloperamp-in-gazebo-editor/, but I'm trying to get a curved ramp rather than a plane.

Cheers,
MB

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22641/skateboard-ramp-in-gazebo-editor/) by [meruz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/11676/meruz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could use a heightmap.

1. Create an PNG image where lightness of a pixel represents its height.

   [image: image description]
2. Make a model out of your picture

   ```
    └── <your_models_folder>
         ├── ...
         └── heightmap
              ├── model.config
              ├── model.sdf
              └── materials
                  └── textures
                      └── heightmap.png
   ```

   you can name the folder containing the model to your liking. I use `heightmap` in this example for easier explanation.

model.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <model>
       <name>Heightmap</name>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <sdf version="1.5">model.sdf</sdf>

       <author>
         <name>TODO</name>
         <email>email@address.org</email>
       </author>

       <description>
         A hightmap plane.
       </description>
     </model>
```

model.sdf

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <sdf version="1.5">
        <model name="heightmap">
          <static>true</static>
          <link name="link">

             <collision name="collision">
              <geometry>
                <heightmap>
                  <uri>model://heightmap/materials/textures/heightmap.png</uri>
                  <size>32 32 .8</size>
                  <pos>0 0 0</pos>
                </heightmap>
              </geometry>
            </collision>

            <visual name="visual">
              <geometry>
                <heightmap>
                  <use_terrain_paging>false</use_terrain_paging>

                  <uri>model://heightmap/materials/textures/heightmap.png</uri>
                  <size>32 32 .8</size>
                  <pos>0 0 0</pos>
                             
                </heightmap>
              </geometry>
            </visual>

          </link>
        </model>
    </sdf>
```

Where the `<size>` tags define the width, length and height of the model. This means that my heightmap will result in terrain 32x32 m large and 80 cm height. The highest point of the terrain will be exactly 80 cm above the lowest. This way you can scale your model. (note that there is `size` tag for both collisions and visuals. You need to keep them the same.)

3. include the heightmap in your WORLD file

   ```
    <include>
         <uri>model://heightmap</uri>
    </include>
   ```
4. launch the world as you normally do.

You can then work on textures for your ramp. This will result in black-and-yellow stripe texture, but the geometry will be there.

You might want to use a picture like the one below for your heightmap.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [meruz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/11676/meruz/) on 2019-06-17**:
Thank you, this is extremely helpful.
I tested your suggestion and it works with the first png file. I then tried the one at the end to play around with something similar to the one I was looking for and that's where I found a couple of issues:

- initially the image not being square
- after adjusting that to 640x640, gazebo started crashing (I try to manually import the map and it stops working)
- after reducing the image to 129x129 no improvement
- created a new one, still crashing

Any advice?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2019-06-17**:
If you run with `--verbose` do you see any messages? I'd expect 640 to fail because the size must be 2^n+1, but 129 should work.

**Comment by [meruz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/11676/meruz/) on 2019-06-19**:
It is now working. It turns out I made a mistake while renaming a few test images (I had one at 128 and one at 129 and used the wrong one for testing). Thank you guys!

**Comment by [mihota](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/18801/mihota/) on 2019-10-30**:
Hi. What software do you guys use to create the png image?

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2019-10-31**:
@mihota I used the GIMP image editor.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You could create an SVG file with the cross-section of the ramp and extrude it using the model editor as described on [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=extrude_svg&cat=model_editor_top).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1